# Blender Benchmark crashes

Tags: performance

I tried to run Blender benchmark because I felt it was a bit slow today working and the GPU was being used intensively in the task manager while sculpting, and I didn't used my new laptop for 3d too much yet. But it crashes when I try to run the GPU benchmark.

My model is the Gigabyte Aero 15 XA Oled, with a i7-9750H (2.6GHz-4.5GHz),NVIDIA® GeForce RTX™ 2070 With Max-Q Design GDDR6 8GB, and an extra 64 ram and 1tb Samsung 970 Evo Plus. (I think it should work very smoothly).

Thanks beforehand.

Comment: @Yohello1 They are likely referring to the Blender Benchmark / Blender Open Data: https://opendata.blender.org/ If you're not familiar with the subject matter, please do some research before commenting. Speculations don't help the asker. Unfounded advice such as "restart[...] your computer" isn't useful either.

Comment: Your hardware should be supported in Blender 2.81. The open data benchmark is still in development and may not be quite up-to-date compared to Blender, apparently there were some issues with RTX cards that haven't been marked as solved yet: https://developer.blender.org/T66415

Comment: Just checked, the benchmark version from the website is quite old (September 2018). I do know that the developers are working on a new version, I'm unsure when it will be released though.